# Whats the best way to prevent water getting to the foundation sill

Tags: waterproofing, stucco

My home is not graded super well, and I was told water has gotten to the sill/wood foundation where this crack is visible.

It's not clear to me what the "proper" way to fix this is. A stucco guy suggested adding flashing as the simplest method. Any other ideas/suggestions

Likewise where the house meets the dirt, what can I do there?

Thank you
[image]?

Answer (score 1):

Around your house your work is cut out for you.  You have to remove the dirt away from the house plus a good overhang or roof eave as they call it also is a big plus in keeping water away.

As far as that front garage wall, I can't see the eave up above but for the time being flashing of some sort is the simplest option.
You can also stack some bricks there too, it will go more with the stucco you have.

At least it looks like you have a positive slope with respect to that wall.